# Slanted Bar at Top of Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently implementing a website, and the ideal design for the main navbar on the home page looks like this:

[image]

I know how to make the links and stuff, but am not sure how to make the blue slanted bar that wraps the links. Obviously a solution would be to just make it part of the background image, but the concerns are that

1) It might not be easy to make responsive

2) We may want the background image to be dynamic or constantly changing, and it would be a pain to constantly have to edit the background images to include the upper slant bar

Some direction on how to do this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of making it part of the background you could make it a separate image. Then place a div at the top of the page and set that blue bar at the top. That way you can scale the div containing the bar independently from the background,

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking into doing an svg path background image.  Here's one I made that looks pretty similar to what you need.

See the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n00epzm3/).

```css
.diagonal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 117px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='navy' preserveAspectRatio='none'><path d='M0 0 L100 0 L100 30 L0 100 Z' /></svg>") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure CSS approach:

```css
#topbar-diagonal {
  border-top: 36px solid #3366FF;
  border-bottom: 36px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100vw solid #3366FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar-diagonal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A really awesome state of the art CSS approach.

```css
  .diagonal {
    border-top: 36px solid #3366FF;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="diagonal"></div>
```

See https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/